# Do I have a bad installation of Bootstrap 3 in my Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have installed two Bootstrap add-ons in my Meteor App and neither one work properly.

First I installed tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker and it works when I click inside the element but until I do that it appears at the very bottom of the page waiting for me to pick a date. It also doesn't display the glyphicon on the form.

Now I installed bootstrap-combobox and it doesn't work at all. It just appear as an ordinary input field with none of my four options showing.

Here is where I installed the files that came with these two add-ons:

```
/myapp/client/  bootstrap-datepicker.js bootstrap-combobox.js
/myapp/client/css/  bootstrap-combobox.css  datepicker.css
```

What can I do to see what I could have done wrong with Bootstrap? This is what I followed during install:

```
meteor add less
meteor add nemo64:bootstrap
```

At the beginning of his tutorial he shows all the installed files in a /lib directory. I have no /lib directory after install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `/lib` directory yourself, as well as `/server` and `/client`, at start of application `/lib` is what Meteor reads first, therefore every collection and allows to them should be placed in there, but you can check details here http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp .

And about bootstrap-3 - try to add whole package to meteor, in lib you add packages that aren't on Atmosphere platforms - https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-use-someone-elses-javascript-in-my-meteor-project

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Thanks. I can tell something happened because my CSS is all messed up, and I'm happy to see that. One would think that they could tell you to create a `/lib` folder and do the installation in there? We all don't inherently know to do that.